# how to make two circles with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-android

I want to make this shape with jetpack compose how can I do it?[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have different options.
One of them is a simple `Box` with an `Icon`:

```
//external circle
Box( 
    contentAlignment= Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(32.dp)
        .border(
            width = 2.dp,
            color = Blue900,
            shape = CircleShape
        ),
){
    //internal circle with icon
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Check,
        contentDescription = "contentDescription",
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(24.dp)
            .background(Blue900, CircleShape)
            .padding(2.dp),
        tint = Blue200
    )
}
```

[image]